# Python how to iterate over a df and output html code

Tags: python, html

I have a spreadsheet with one row per person. I also have html code to create a table for each person in the spreadsheet. I would like to iterate over the spreadsheet and output the html table code for each person, which I will paste into Qualtrics.

Does anyone have a fairly simple approach to this? I'm still relatively new to Python. I thought I could just use Pandas to read the Excel file and iterate over it using strings to fill in the html code. Like this:

```
    for i in df.index:
        print(
"""<table>
  <tbody><tr>
    <td style="color: purple; font-size: 22pt;"><strong>"""+df['Name']+"""[i]</strong></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="font-size: 9pt;"><i>"""+df['Title'][i]+"""</i></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>""")
```

That approach did not work at all. I started looking at Flask, but I haven't been able to figure out the iteration part and it feels like there is probably a simpler way to do this anyway. Thanks for any suggestions!

EDIT: 
Just to clarify the output I was looking for, I wanted to print the html code for 100 tables. The html for each table is the same (sample below), but I would pull Name, Title, etc. from rows of the dataframe. Outputting an html file with 100 tables as described would also work as I could get the html from the source code.

```
<table>
  <tbody><tr>
    <td style="color: purple; font-size: 22pt;"><strong>Name</strong></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="font-size: 9pt;"><i>Title</i></td>
  </tr>
</tbody></table>
```

Comment: You might consider a template library like jinja2. It will make it possible to loop and do other control flow structures within a html page: http://jinja.pocoo.org/ If I remember correctly I think it is what powers Flask's html templating. Other than that you also have `df.to_html(...)` from pandas itself. Haven't tried it but might work.

Comment: Your question is a bit vague on what your input is, what you want your output to be, what your actual output is, and how those last two are different. `print` just sends things to the console, so if you want to actually do something with the output, you'll have to save it somehow.

Comment: @ Andrew C: Thanks! I was starting down that path. Jinja/Flask certainly sound interesting and worth learning, even if I don't use them here.

Comment: @Acccumulation:  I'll update my question to be a little clearer. I would like to print the html code for 100 tables, pulling data from a df to input into the tables. If it's easier, the output could be an html file, like flask would do, and I could get the html from the source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think a simple approach would be to just create a formula in the first row of your Excel spreadsheet that concatenates the html and a person's information using the & operator.  Then just copy the formula down for the remaining rows. Once you've done that you can copy the column to Qualtrics.

Comment: Nailed it. I wasn't able to copy it straight to Qualtrics because it kept the double quotes. I copied and pasted values to another cell, then I had to copy that into Word, and finally I could copy it into Qualtrics. I wish I could do it more directly from Excel, but this will work in this instance. Thank you!

Comment: If you just want to concatenate columns, pandas will broadcast the `+` operator, i.e `df[col1]+df[col2]` will generate a column in which entry is the concatenation of `df[colq]` and `df[col2]` for that row.

Comment: For future reference, if you change the html (style) double quotes to single quotes you can copy your Excel cells into Qualtrics without any extra effort.